# Is there anyway to check that how many times a controlled method invoked through IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

We are using ASP.NET MVC application, We have some ASP.NET MVC Web API controller and some implementation, We needs to check that how many times it has been invoked through IIS, is there anyway to find how many times that Web API has been used from some point of time?

Comment: Considering the controller is simply the result of accessing a url, couldn't you just query the [request logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httplogging) generated by IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) .When working on applications, you may often want to log application data that may include, the sequence of events in your application,etc . Add log in the controller method

```
           //Controller Method
            public string GETTOKEN() 
            {
                log.Info("I am Invoked "+DateTime.Now); //Log4net
                //Your Code
            }
```

result :[image]
Hope this helps you

Comment: But it need some implementation for logs right, but I just wants to know is it possible to check through IIS, anyway thanks for the suggestion @user202